# Alternative for HttpActionContext.RequestContentKeyValueModel on ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Since from version beta of ASP.NET Web API, I have used `HttpActionContext.RequestContentKeyValueModel` to get input parameters from body of POST request:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var requestContentKeyValueModel = actionContext.RequestContentKeyValueModel;
    //Do something in here

    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
}
```

but in the new release version RC, this property disappeared, is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form`.

**EDIT**

You can always hide it behind interface:

```
public interface IKeyValueProvider
{
    string GetValue(string key);
}

class RequestFormKeyValueProvider : IKeyValueProvider
{
    public string GetValue(string key)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[key];
    }
}
```

Inject `IKeyValueProvider` in your controllers and mock in your tests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes, it works for me, however, with this approach we cannot do unit test, I would prefer this support is from Web Api.